# Error in installation of Magento on wamp server (The connection was reset)

Tags: wordpress, magento, wamp

It keeps saying "The connection was reset" while I'm trying to open magento project under "Your Projects" on the wamp dashboard.

I'm using the same wamp server to host a wordpress project under "Your Projects" on the wamp dashboard and its working fine on opening the project.

Can someone tell me what could be the issue here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eleminate the possible faults in your connection, try to make instalation on localhost, not on a client browser. Magento have a large tables inserts during installation / or first running, is possible you have the browser timeout issue.